# Calling a function from serial port handler took too much time and processor power

Tags: c#, serial-port

i am getting data from serial port interface each data stream (packet) consist of 1kbytes. these values are basic digital oscilloscope analog signals. After processing these datas i draw the signals to the screen.

The problem is if i call the function which process the signals from serial port "DataReceivedHandler" it takes too much time(200mS) and too much process power. But when i call my function seperatly like via button click it took 10mS. After debugging too many times i couln't find why is this taking too long? what are the possible reasons for this? can you give me some solutions?

In two examples below results are correct but time consuming different.

```
public void DataReceivedHandler(
                 object sender,
                 SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    int temp_buffer_count;
            


    temp_buffer_count = sp.BytesToRead;

    label55.Text += temp_buffer_count.ToString() + "--";
    serialPort1.Read(readBuffer, uart_count, temp_buffer_count);

    uart_count += temp_buffer_count;

    if(uart_count>3)
    {
        int dataadet = readBuffer[1] * 256 + readBuffer[2] + 3;

        if(uart_count>= dataadet)
        {
            if(readBuffer[0]==0xff)
            {
                UdpReceivedData = new byte[dataadet + 100];
                Array.Copy(readBuffer, ReceivedData, dataadet);

              
                uart_count = 0;
                dataadet = 0;

                if(ReceivedData[3]==AdcDataIslemi)
                {
                    stopwatch2.Resart();
                    //this function tooks too much time
                    PreparePage(false, true);
                    stopwatch2.Stop();
                }

            }
                 

        }

    }
```

}

if i call same function with a button click that function is executing 20 times faster.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch2.Resart();
        PreparePage(false, true);
        stopwatch2.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Stopwatch is not a good benchmarking tool. We also don't see what PeparePage does and thus cannot say, how the two methods of calling it may influence execution time. What I would suggest generally, though is to decouple data reception from processing it. For example by using Data Flow.

Comment: Thanks for answer. PeparePage does some mathematical operations to the 1Kbyte packet. if i process this packet via buton everthing is ok. But inside DataReceivedHandler someting takes huge process power. I also tried timer. instead calling PeparePage i started a timer and after 1000ms when timer tick i called PeparePage. but again nothing changed and still took huge time.

Comment: Again, cannot tell. As is, I would _guess_ `button2_Click` calls `PreparePage` on the UI thread, while `DataReceivedHandler` does not. That _could_ be part of the miracle. When using a timer, it depends which kind of timer. There's `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer`...

Comment: you are right thanks again.

Comment: You shouldn't do complex math in your DataReceived Event, that will cause it to be slow and or not work properly.  You need a separate thread where you do the complex math.

Comment: thanks it can be the problem. when i execute outside of thread everyting is normal.